# Vue error Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded on updating computed value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my code under computed

```
 computed: {
      display: {
        get() {
          return this.display
        },
        set(newValue) {
          this.display = newValue
        }
      }
    },
```

i am trying to update the value of computed from a function under model

```
async submit() {
        this.display = false;
}
```

while submit function runs, i get below error on console

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: @JaromandaX I did not get you. Can you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: That was an typo in the question. its not this.abc.

Comment: my mistake, thought you were using getters and setters - whereas you arent

Comment: but ... still ... why is `submit` async? there's nothing asynchronous about it - remove the `async` tag, see if that helps

Comment: there is more code after `this.display = false;` which needs the submit function to be `async`. @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, wait ... this is vue, so those are getters and setters ... right ... the problem is, that you can't have a setter for a property that updates that property ... it's infinite recursion

Comment: consider the usual way getters and setters are done ... `var x = {
    set display(name) {
        x.display = name;
    },
    get display() {
        return x.display;
    }
}` ... try setting or getting `x.display` ... you can't do that

Comment: I have update my code to ``` set(newValue) {
          newValue
        }```. It does not work too. Value is not getting updated

Comment: you need to learn what setters and getters are - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get should help

Comment: why can't `display` be `data` instead of `computed`? I mean, the code you posted won't work, but all it attempts to do is use `display` as if it were declared in `data` instead ... let me guess *there's more code I'm not showing because I didn't think it was relevant* ... or maybe a watcher ... certainly not computed

Comment: i am getting the value from props send by parents component, which is not allowed to update in child component.

Comment: so "display" is a prop?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes

Answer (score 3):

When you write `this.display = newValue` in the `set` it will just cause the `set` to be called again, going round and round in a loop.

To wrap a prop in a computed property you need to give it a different name. Further, the `set` should be emitting an event so that the parent component can update the data. You can't do it directly within the current component.

The example below uses the `sync` modifier but you could use a separate event listener if you prefer.

```js
const Child = {
  template: `<input v-model="displayModel">`,

  props: ['display'],
  
  computed: {
    displayModel: {
      get () {
        return this.display
      },
      
      set (display) {
        this.$emit('update:display', display)
      }
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    Child
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      parentDisplay: 'hello'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ parentDisplay }}</p>
  <child :display.sync="parentDisplay"></child>
</div>
```

You could also just `emit` the event directly rather than modifying the property at all, skipping the computed property altogether. i.e. Replace `this.display = false;` with an `$emit`.

Alternatively, if the prop is used only to set the initial value of the property then you should just copy it across to a `data` property when the component is first created:

```js
props: ['display'],

data () {
  return {
    internalDisplay: this.display
  }
}
```

You can then set the value of `internalDisplay` directly.